# Displaying a video onLoad

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, onload

What I would like is to have a video play in full screen once and then disappear leaving the web page behind. is this possible using Javascript, HTML and possibly CSS?

The video in question is called Website Opening.mp4

Answer (score 1):

```
<video width="100%" autoplay="autoplay">
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Edit: When autoplay attribute is present, the video will automatically start playing as soon as it can i.e. when the page loads.

Comment: Now all you have to do to fully answer the OP's question is writing that html in a handler for the onload event.

Comment: Also notice that the video tag is not supported by Internet Explorer 8 and earlier. But then again, whomever is using IE and hasn't upgraded to 9/10 should have their internet access cut off for the good of humanity anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to get the video to vanish after it has played once?

Comment: @DaveLabal you could always use a little jQuery. Give a containing div an id and `$("#id").fadeOut("slow", function () { /* anything else you wanna do here */ })`;

Comment: if using jwPlayer to play your video, you hide the placeholder of the video at the end of the video.

Comment: I have never had experience at using jQuery so I am a little confused as to how I would use that? Also i dont believe I am using jwPlayer, I am just using video tags, If it is simple to do I'd be interested in converting my coding to use jwPlayer